# AppCompatTextView autoSizeTextType is weird with hint

Tags: android, android-textview-autosize

I've been experiencing very weird behavior of `AppCompatTextView`'s `autoSizeTextType`. 
I found where the problem is but i don't get it at all.
There is a `AppCompatTextView` in a `ConstraintLayout`. it's only child of the XML.

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/testView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hello World!"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="10dp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="7dp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the result is like this below.
[image] 
[image] 
Can you see it? i didn't make the hint horizontally to show like that.
But if i change the 7dp with 10dp, the problem will be gone.

[image]

But i can't do that because the `autoSizeMaxTextSize` and `autoSizeMinTextSize` should not be the same. 
What's happening here now? is it a bug?

### Edit)

The only workdaround that i just found is to set `android:ellipisze="end"`. the middle, start, marquee also work well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **app** with **android**

app will assign values from values.xml

android will assign values from attrs.xml

```
  <!-- The minimum text size constraint to be used when auto-sizing text. -->
        <attr name="autoSizeMinTextSize" format="dimension" />
        <!-- The maximum text size constraint to be used when auto-sizing text. -->
        <attr name="autoSizeMaxTextSize" format="dimension" />
```

> ```
> android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="10dp"
> android:autoSizeMinTextSize="7dp"
> ```

Comment: the problem is still same and my project supports API 21 and `android:autoSizeMaaxTextSize` can be used from API 26 or higher.